# Replace selection with updated string

Tags: eclipse, replace

I need to refactor quite some code by adding translation info to fixed strings. In many places I need to replace text like this:

```
Some Text
```

into

```
{% trans "Some Text" %}
```

I would like to select the string and then use some kind of key combo to update what I selected.

How would I do that in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Search` Menu then `Files` 
in `Containing Text` : write  `Some Text` 
Then you have a button `Replace` 
A window called `Replace Text Matches` is open. 
 In `With` : you write `{% trans "Some Text" %}` 
Finally push the button `Preview` after seeing your modifications press the button `OK`

Comment: The problem is, `Some Text` is different every time.

Comment: There is a lot of text to change ?